# Cannot Convert String to Integer error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In my ruby code I am running into a "cannot convert string to Integer" error. The code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'

# Now you will fetch /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json,
# returns a list of public Tweets from the specified
# account.


  baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"
path    = "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
query   = URI.encode_www_form(
    "q" => "Obama"
    "count" => 1
    )
address = URI("#{baseurl}#{path}?#{query}")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri

# Print data about a list of Tweets
def print_timeline(tweets)
  tweets.each do |tweet|
  require 'date'
   d = DateTime.parse(tweet['created_at'])
    puts " #{tweet['text'].delete ","} , #{d.strftime('%d.%m.%y')} , #{tweet['user']   ['name']}, #{tweet['id']}"
  end
end

# Set up HTTP.
http             = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
http.use_ssl     = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

# If you entered your credentials in the first
# exercise, no need to enter them again here. The
# ||= operator will only assign these values if
# they are not already set.
consumer_key = OAuth::Consumer.new(
    "")
access_token = OAuth::Token.new(
    "")

# Issue the request.
request.oauth! http, consumer_key, access_token
http.start
response = http.request request

# Parse and print the Tweet if the response code was 200
tweets = nil

puts "Text,Date,Name,id"
if response.code == '200' then
  tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
  print_tweets(tweets)
end
nil
```

After debugging, I believe the error is coming from lines 19 or 20 (d = and puts statement). I am not sure what String is attempting to be converted to an integer.

Comment: What's the value of `tweet` at that point?

Comment: Tweet is a local variable that is a string in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access `tweet['created_at']` whereas tweet is not a Hash structure. You should try to inspect the structure of `tweet` ( and maybe of `tweets` as well ).

You can look at the class with `tweet.class` or directly inspect it : `tweet.inspect`

I'd guess `tweet` is an array, and its elements should therefore be called using an integer, not a string

Comment: I am new to Ruby and writing on CodeAcademy so it is tough to debug. If tweet is an array, which would make sense due to all the information being stored, would there be away to change its elements to strings? Or another way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you tell us what `tweet.inspect` yields ? It would be easier to answer your question more precisely

Comment: in the loop when i print tweet.inspect it returns(only part of return):  ["statuses", [{"metadata"=>{"result_type"=>"recent", "iso_language_code"=>"en"}, "created_at"=>"Tue Jun 18 15:51:10 +0000 2013", "id"=>347018659639726082, "id_str"=>"347018659639726082", "text"=>"…then Obama came for the Downloaders http://t.co/IoBrQI37zQ @datechguy Hit the tip jar, if you're able."

Comment: well in this case you want to access `tweet[1][0]['created_at']` or equivalently, `tweet[1].first['created_at']` .

`tweet[1].first` is supposed to access the Hash structure that you are trying to read. Hope this helps

Comment: careful, you'll also have to change `tweet['text']`, `tweet['user']`...etc using the same logic

Comment: Oh ok. So I would have to directly reference each field of the array?

Comment: In my opinion you should create a variable that contains the useful values : `tweet_hash = tweet[1].first`.

Then you just have to use `tweet_hash['created_at']` instead of `tweet['created_at']`... and so on